# Add gaze buttons to scene using A-frame

Tags: events, controls, aframe, gaze-buttons

Is there a way to add gaze buttons in [aframe](/questions/tagged/aframe)? Note also for a better experience there must be an little progress bar to know how long the user must look to it.

I've looked inside the inspector tools but nothing found that works.

[image]

In [this YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yM89f0GLzB0), I've found how to add click controls. Is it the same way I could make gaze events?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select an item by gazing at it using the fuse property of the cursor component. Check the A-Frame docs here:
https://aframe.io/docs/0.5.0/components/cursor.html#fuse-based-cursor

This will trigger a click event on the item, so you also need to have a listener set up on the item for the click event.

Answer (score 1):

By searching, I've found a solution that works. Here is my code:

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('a-sphere')[0].addEventListener('click', function(){
    alert('click');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.5.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<a-scene>
    <!-- this is my object that must execute a click event when looked -->
    <a-sphere position="0 0 -7" color="red">
    </a-sphere>

    <!-- camera -->
    <a-camera look-controls wasd-controls cursor="maxDistance: 30; fuse: true">
        <!-- progress bar -->
        <a-entity position="0 0 -3" geometry="primitive: ring; radiusOuter: 0.07;radiusInner: 0.05;" material="color: cyan; shader: flat"
            cursor="maxDistance: 30; fuse: true">
            <!--<a-cursor color="red"></a-cursor>-->
            <a-animation begin="click" easing="ease-in" attribute="scale" fill="backwards" from="0.1 0.1 0.1" to="1 1 1" dur="150"></a-animation>
            <a-animation begin="fusing" easing="ease-in" attribute="scale" fill="forwards" from="1 1 1" to="0.1 0.1 0.1" dur="1500"></a-animation>
        </a-entity>
    </a-camera>
</a-scene>
```

Thanks to @thoragio for his/her answer.