# Simulate aframe look controls

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe

I would like to simulate a user input in my Webvr application. Is there any way to simulate look controls in Aframe?

```
<a-entity listener position="0 0 0" id="camera" camera="userHeight: 1.6" look-controls>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add gaze buttons to scene using A-frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43046362/add-gaze-buttons-to-scene-using-a-frame)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simulate user input and somehow pass that into `look-controls` would be extremely difficult. If you're determined, check out the [WebVR API Emulation](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/webvr-api-emulation/gbdnpaebafagioggnhkacnaaahpiefil?hl=en) chrome extension and its code.

What would be easier, though, is to implement your own A-Frame component for controls, perhaps using `look-controls` as the starting point. I've done this several times, to write controls for gamepad, teleportation, touch-screen-to-move, and so on. Check out the controls components in a-frame extras here: https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/tree/master/src/controls. If those don't work for you, you can use it as a starting point for your own code, or register an extension to `universal-controls`.

Answer (score 2):

You could also try https://github.com/dmarcos/aframe-motion-capture-components to record/replay/simulate head and controller movements/events. Doesn't support listening to window click yet though.